# sending attatchement using mail php function

Tags: php

Hello this is code for sending a text along with an attachment it only send the text not the attachment i did my best but i did not found it. any one visit my code and edit it and back post it to me it will be so kind of you.

Help me plz.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['propertystatus'])) 

{

    $email_to = "contact@scale-property.com";
    $email_subject = "New Property From Customer";
    $email_subject_to_user = "Copy of your email";
    $propery_Information = 'PROPERTY INFORMATION';
    $propery_Location = 'PROPERTY LOCATION';
    $contact_Information = 'CONTACT INFORMATION';


        // Allowed file types. add file extensions WITHOUT the dot.
    $allowtypes=array("zip", "rar", "doc", "pdf");

        // Require a file to be attached: false = Do not allow attachments true = allow only 1 file to be attached
    $requirefile="true";

    // Maximum file size for attachments in KB NOT Bytes for simplicity. MAKE SURE your php.ini can handel it,
    // post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, file_uploads, max_execution_time!
    // 2048kb = 2MB,       1024kb = 1MB,     512kb = 1/2MB etc..
    $max_file_size="1024";

    // Thank you message
    $thanksmessage="Your attachments has also been sent successfully.";

    $errors = array(); //Initialize error array

    $error_message = "";



    function died($error) 
    {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were errors found with the form you submitted.<br>";

        echo $error."<br />";

        die();

    }  


    // checks for required file
    // http://amiworks.co.in/talk/handling-file-uploads-in-php/
    if($requirefile=="true") {
        if($_FILES['attachment']['error']==4) {
            $errors[]='You forgot to attach a file';
        }
    }


        //checks attachment file
    // checks that we have a file
    if((!empty($_FILES["attachment"])) && ($_FILES['attachment']['error'] == 0)) {
            // basename -- Returns filename component of path
            $filename = basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
            $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
            $filesize=$_FILES['attachment']['size'];
            $max_bytes=$max_file_size*1024;

            //Check if the file type uploaded is a valid file type. 
            if (!in_array($ext, $allowtypes)) {
                $errors[]="Invalid extension for your file: <strong>".$filename."</strong>";

        // check the size of each file
        } elseif($filesize > $max_bytes) {
                $errors[]= "Your file: <strong>".$filename."</strong> is to big. Max file size is ".$max_file_size."kb.";
            }

    }


        // if !empty FILES

    if (empty($errors))
     { //If everything is OK

        // send an email
        // Obtain file upload vars
        $fileatt      = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
        $fileatt_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
        $fileatt_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];


        // create a boundary string. It must be unique
          $semi_rand = md5(time());
          $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";


       // Add the headers for a file attachment
          $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                      "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n".
                      " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

          // Add a multipart boundary above the plain message
          $email_message .="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
          $email_message .="--{$mime_boundary}\n";
          $email_message .="Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
          $email_message .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
          $email_message .="From: ".$namefrom."\n\n";

        if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) {
          // Read the file to be attached ('rb' = read binary)
          $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
          $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
          fclose($file);

          // Base64 encode the file data
          $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

          // Add file attachment to the message
          $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                      "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
                      " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                      //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                      //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                      $data . "\n\n" .
                      "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
        }

        $envs = array("HTTP_USER_AGENT", "REMOTE_ADDR", "REMOTE_HOST");
        foreach ($envs as $env)
        $email_message .= "$env: $_SERVER[$env]\n";

    } //end of if(empty($errors))


    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['propertystatus']) ||

        !isset($_POST['currencytype']) ||

        !isset($_POST['currency']) ||

        !isset($_POST['rooms']) ||

        !isset($_POST['bathroom']) ||

        !isset($_POST['kitchen']) ||

        !isset($_POST['yard']) ||

        !isset($_POST['housedesproperty']) ||

        !isset($_POST['drop_1']) ||

        !isset($_POST['drop_2']) ||

        !isset($_POST['drop_3']) ||

        !isset($_POST['region']) ||

        !isset($_POST['street']) ||

        !isset($_POST['name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['emailadd']) ||

        !isset($_POST['conemailadd']) ||

        !isset($_POST['phone1']) ||

        !isset($_POST['phone2']))

    {

        died('You have not properly selected the fields.');      

    }   

    $property_status = $_POST['propertystatus']; // required
    $currency_type = $_POST['currencytype']; // required
    $currency = $_POST['currency']; // required
    $rooms = $_POST['rooms']; // required
    $bathroom = $_POST['bathroom']; // required
    $kitchen = $_POST['kitchen']; // required
    $yard = $_POST['yard']; // required
    $housedesproperty = $_POST['housedesproperty']; // required
    $drop_1 = $_POST['drop_1']; // required
    $drop_2 = $_POST['drop_2']; // required
    $drop_3 = $_POST['drop_3']; // required
    $region = $_POST['region']; // required
    $street = $_POST['street']; // required
    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $emailadd = $_POST['emailadd']; // required
    $conemailadd = $_POST['conemailadd']; // required
    $phone1 = $_POST['phone1']; // required
    $phone2 = $_POST['phone2']; // required

    $email_message = "Property details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) 
    {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }

    $email_message .= "".clean_string($propery_Information)."\n";
    $email_message .= "--------------------------------------------"."\n";
    $email_message .= "Property Status: ".clean_string($property_status)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Total Price: ".clean_string($currency_type)." ".(number_format($currency, 2, '.', ','))."\n";
    $email_message .= "Rooms: ".clean_string($rooms)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Bathrooms: ".clean_string($bathroom)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Bathrooms: ".clean_string($kitchen)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Bathrooms: ".clean_string($yard)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Description: ".clean_string($housedesproperty)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "".clean_string($propery_Location)."\n";
    $email_message .= "--------------------------------------------"."\n";
    $email_message .= "Province: ".clean_string($drop_1)."\n";
    $email_message .= "District: ".clean_string($drop_2)."\n";
    $email_message .= "PD(Nahya): ".clean_string($drop_3)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Bathrooms: ".clean_string($region)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Street: ".clean_string($street)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "".clean_string($contact_Information)."\n";
    $email_message .= "--------------------------------------------"."\n";
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email ID: ".clean_string($emailadd)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Con-Email ID: ".clean_string($conemailadd)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone(1): ".clean_string($phone1)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone(2): ".clean_string($phone2)."\n";

// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$emailadd."\r\n".


'Reply-To: '.$emailadd."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
@mail($emailadd, $email_subject_to_user, $email_message, "From: $email_to");

?> 
Your Property has been Posted please check your email address.
<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: Duplicate of your own question, [Images not sending to to inbox of my email, using PHP mail()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360692/images-not-sending-to-to-inbox-of-my-email-using-php-mail)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer).  It's a PHP class that handles advanced mailing functions, including sending attachments, with very little effort.

Comment: sorry i m new to php so i dont know how to start working with PHPMailer

Comment: This page has some code snippets that show you how to get started with it. Once you use it, you'll love it! http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial

Comment: thanks alot any trusted source of PHPMailer to downlad

Comment: i did google and gound this one http://www.phphq.net/scripts.php is it a best one for donwloading